# Integration of text to speech

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want to integrate text to speech service though node js in my chatbot.Eg: i give a text as input and the voice should reach directly through the speaker.
How do i do that? 
what type of service/api should I use?

Answer (score 0):

i know p5.js has a voice synthesis library called p5.speech dont know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Is this a solution or a comment?